# Word Syntax Error with NumPages and Formula

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, field-codes

I'm trying to use the following as a field in word:

```
{ = { NumPages } - 1 }
```

And I get the following error:

> !Syntax
>   Error, {

I seem to be using the right format per [Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/field-codes-numpages-field-HA102017464.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102749146). Any ideas? Thanks as always.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The following are the steps that you will have to follow to do what you are 
after:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to reveal the field codes.
2. Select the whole of the `{NUMPAGES}` field including the `{` and `}`
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> - this will place a pair of braces `{` `}` around the 
   NUMPAGES field so that it now looks like:

   ```
   { {NUMPAGES} }
   ```
4. Between the { {, insert an = sign, and between the } } insert -1 so 
   that the field now looks like:

   ```
   {={NUMPAGES}-1}
   ```
5. Now press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to hide the field codes and select the field, which 
   will still probably shown the total number of pages and press <kbd>F9</kbd> to update 
   the fields.  You should now have the result that you are after.

Previewing the document will also update the fields as will printing it if the `Update Fields` box is checked under the `Tools>Options>Print` menu item (newer versions will put it in `File>Options>Display`).

[image]

The main thing to remember when working with fields is that you must use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to insert a pair of `{` `}`.  Typing them in from the keyboard does not work.

Comment: I'm still getting the syntax error message. See my code in the original answer - it is identical to your code. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: It may look the same but if you don't follow these instructions to the letter it is not the same. I've tested this myself and I assure you that it is correct.

Comment: Thanks, @krowe! I confirm that your instructions work. The main thing to remember part, about using Ctrl+F9 to insert curly braces, is what did the trick for me.

Comment: @krowe, I followed your instruction, but at last returns **!Invalid Character Setting**.

Comment: @mgae2m If it says that then it means that you did NOT follow my instructions. This is why I told you to be careful and follow the instructions as they are written; not as you expect them to be.

Comment: @krowe  I stumbled on this answer because I also had the  `!Invalid Character Setting` error.  For me, the solution was to reset some of the regional settings of Windows 10 (Control Panel -> Change date, time, or number formats -> Additional settings -> Reset).

Answer (score 3):

For those who can't get it right using Mark's advice:
I have a Word 2010 and for me the trick is to add **each** pair of braces using Ctrl+F9.
Don't type {NUMPAGES}. Type NUMPAGES, select it and press Ctrl+F9 instead.

Comment: Also applies to Word 2016. I noticed that the generated braces were in bold font (like those inserted around the entire field) whereas my typed braces were in regular font.

Answer (score 2):

@Vladipolis, what you wrote is THE key to this whole strange operation.  I could not get math involving page references to work until I followed your instructions.  In short, each field needs to be an independent "object", or it won't work.

In my case, I wanted to get the count of pages, excluding the number of pages in the section.

This does ***not*** work (even though it would be a lot easier if it did!):

1. Type `= { NUMPAGES } - { SECTIONPAGES }`
2. Select that entire block of text and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>(this will actually fail to turn it into a proper field even though it might *look* like it worked)

This **does** work:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to reveal field codes
2. Type `NUMPAGES`
3. Select `NUMPAGES` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to turn it into a proper field
4. Type `SECTIONPAGES` to the right of the `{ NUMPAGES }` field
5. Select `SECTIONPAGES` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to turn it into a proper field
6. Type `=` to the left of the `{ NUMPAGES }` field
7. Type `-` between the `{ NUMPAGES }` and `{ SECTIONPAGES }` fields
8. Select `= { NUMPAGES } - { SECTIONPAGES }` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to turn the whole thing into a proper field (of nested fields!)